# How to use commas if the conjunction “and” is repeated?

Tags: punctuation, commas

For example,

> Mary bought bread and meat and cheese and some butter.

Do I have to put any commas in this sentence? If the answer is yes, then how many commas and where should they stand?

Comment: For some reason, this question reminds me of Hemingway, a lot. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Punctuation is a matter of style. The usage of multiple **and**s is unconventional, and I don't know of any style guides have any recommendations for this.

Normally, you would replace all except the final **and** with commas:

> Mary bought bread, meat, cheese and some butter.

There is an alternative scheme where you also place an [Oxford Comma](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-is-the-oxford-comma) before the final **and**:

> Mary bought bread, meat, cheese, and some butter.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said, in a list which contains three items or more, in most cases it is better to replace all *and*s except the last one with commas. Such pattern, with a single conjunction, is used in majority of contexts.
But there are a few situations where repeated *and*s may be a better choice. In English, commas are not restricted to separate items in lists; sometimes they are used to set off appositions. Thus, in such cases repeated conjunctions may be used to resolve ambiguity. For example, let's take the sentence:

> They went to Oregon with Betty, a maid(,) and a cook.

Suppose that there were three persons: 1) Betty; 2) maid; 3) cook. If we write the sentence above as *They went to Oregon with Betty, a maid and a cook.*, without the Oxford comma, then there's a possibility that the entire construction 'a maid and a cook' is an apposition to 'Betty', which means that there was only one person. If we try to use the Oxford comma, or a serial comma, then the sentence will look as follows: *They went to Oregon with Betty, a maid, and a cook.* Now, it would be still possible to understand the word 'maid' as an apposition to the noun ‘Betty’, so the sentence could mean that there were only two persons: 1) Betty (who was also a maid); 2) a cook.
However, if we rewrite our phrase using two *and*s, then we should obtain:
*They went to Oregon with Betty and a maid and a cook.* Here, it is completely clear that they were accompanied by three distinct persons. ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma))
Usually, construction "x and y and z..." does not require any commas inside of it:

> [I have English and math and science homework.](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-8/conjunctions-and-interjections/lesson-1/coordinate-conjunctions)

There are some writers who prefer this style, although it is not widespread. Still, it can be totally possible to use more than one *and* without using commas in the same phrase in prose or in poetry.